# control & disable a dropdown button in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I wanted to control a drop-down button and make it unclickable using a button.

Is there any way to make it disable. Basically not allowing it able to change.

```
new DropdownButton(
          value: animalName,
          items: animals.map(
            (String value) {
              return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: new Text('$value'),
              );
            },
          ).toList(),
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              animalName = value;
            });
          },
        ),
```

So this is the code I currently use on the drop-down button, but i cant disabled it.

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Found this in the [DropdownButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton/onChanged.html) docs:

> If items or onChanged is null, the button will be disabled, the down arrow will be grayed out, and the disabledHint will be shown (if provided)

```
DropdownButton(
  onChanged: null,
  items: [...],
)
```

Comment: Awsome! It would be much better if there was an "enabled" constructor parameter.

Answer (score 27):

This isn't what you want to hear, but I don't think there's currently an easy way. I experimented with simply removing all the items and that causes a nice little crash. Maybe worth raising an issue with the flutter people on github...

There is an alternative that may be good enough for you for now. If you wrap your DropdownButton in an IgnorePointer, when you want it to be disabled you can change IgnorePointer's `ignoring` property to true.

That way if the user taps on it, it won't do anything.

But you'll probably want to indicate to the user somehow that it's disabled as well, something like setting the hint text (as it's grey).

```
      child: new IgnorePointer(
        ignoring: true,
        child: new DropdownButton(
          hint: new Text("disabled"),
            items: ["asdf", "wehee", "asdf2", "qwer"].map(
              (String value) {
                return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                  value: value,
                  child: new Text('$value'),
                );
              },
            ).toList(),
          onChanged: (value) {},
        ),
```

Answer (score 14):

You can make `DropdownButtonFormField` or `DropdownButton` disabled if set `onChanged` to null, and if you want that dropdown still shows selected value you must set `disabledHint`. For example:

```
     DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
        disabledHint: Text(_selectedItem),
        value: _selectedItem,
        onChanged: enabled ? (value) => setState(() => _selectedItem = value) : null,
        items: items.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((item) {
          return DropdownMenuItem(
            value: item,
            child: Text(item),
          );
        }).toList(),
      )
```

Answer (score 12):

Just wrap it with **`IgnorePointer`** widget to make **`DropdownButton`** disable

```
IgnorePointer(
      ignoring:  enabled,
      child: new DropdownButton(
          value: animalName,
          items: animals.map(
            (String value) {
              return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: new Text('$value'),
              );
            },
          ).toList(),
          onChanged: (value) {
            setState(() {
              animalName = value;
            });
          },
        ),
);
```

Answer (score 4):

> If items or onChanged is null, the button will be disabled, the down
>   arrow will be grayed out, and the disabledHint will be shown (if
>   provided)

So something like this should work:

```
DropdownButton<String>(
  ...
  onChanged: this.enabled ? (id) => setState(() => this.id = id) : null,
)
```

Comment: problem with this is that if disabled, the value property does not reflect and selects it by default

Answer (score 3):

okay, i found a trick that satisfied me
i wanted it hide/show the [DropdownButton](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html) depending on [CheckboxListTile](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/CheckboxListTile-class.html)

in [StatefulWidget](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) Class
first create a function ex:

```
  _buildDropDown(bool enable) {
    if (enable) {
      return DropdownButton<String>(
        hint: Text("Hint"),
        items: <String>[
          'item 1',
          'item 2',
          'item 3',
        ].map((String value) {
          return new DropdownMenuItem<String>(
            value: value,
            child: new Text(value),
          );
        }).toList(),
        onChanged: (value) {},
      );
    } else { // Just Divider with zero Height xD
      return Divider(color: Colors.white, height: 0.0);
    }
  }
```

and now in build

```
bool enable = true;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Column(
    children: <Widget>[
      CheckboxListTile(
        title: const Text('Switcher'),
        selected: true,
        value: enable,
        onChanged: (bool value) {
          setState(() {
            enable = value;
          });
        },
      ),
      _buildDropDown(enable),
    ],
  );
}
```

now every time you change enable it will display and hide the [DropdownButton](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html)

Comment: Just return an empty `Container`, e.g. `return Container();`

Answer (score 3):

```
DropdownButtonFormField(
     onChange: isDisable ? null : (str){
        
     },
     disabledHint: isDisable ?  null : Text('Your hint text'),
     ...
)
```

**For disable
*onChange: null***

**For disable Caption
d*isabledHint: Text('Your hint text')***

Comment: disable hint should be with NOT 
disabledHint: !isDisable ?  null : Text('Your hint text'),

Answer (score 0):

> **//add widget'AbsorbPointer' true-disable,false-enable**
>
> // **isEditable = ture**

```
AbsorbPointer(
    absorbing: isEditable
    DropdownButton(
    onChanged: null,
    items: [...],
    )
)
```

Answer (score -1):

Simple:

```
decoration:InputDecoration(enabled: false),
```